# Dangerous conversion from int to longlong: No warning?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
UINT One = 1;
LONG     mylong      = LONG(-1) * One;
LONGLONG mylonglong1 = LONG(-1) * One;
LONGLONG mylonglong2 = LONG(LONG(-1) * One);
```

What would be the value stored in `mylong`, `mylonglong1` and `mylonglong2` ?

```
mylong      = 0xffffffff         (ok)
mylonglong1 = 0x00000000ffffffff (why?)
mylonglong2 = 0xffffffffffffffff (ok)
```

I was really surprised to know the result of `mylonglong1`, and more surprised that there is no compilation warning.

Why assigning a LONG to a LONGLONG is causing that left padding with zeros?

---

What really happened in a project is a problem in using the function CFile::Seek()

```
virtual LONG Seek( LONG lOff, UINT nFrom );
```

defined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270542(v=vs.60).aspx
migrated to

```
virtual ULONGLONG Seek( LONGLONG lOff, UINT nFrom);
```

defined here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b2eb5757-d499-4e67-b044-dd7d1abaa0f8.aspx#cfile__seek

After migration it no longer worked because the argument conversion of `lOff` was not giving the expected result.

Comment: did you confuse SO with a guessing game site? To know the answer one can simply run the code and print the values, no?

Comment: What's the aversion to running it with a debugger?

Comment: Since everyone was complaining over the format of the question rather than the content I rewrote it. Hopefully it fits the format better now and will attract a normal answer.

Comment: Thank you CompuChip for your constructive action in rewriting my question. Though I decided to rewrite it myself again to make it really reflect my initial question. But now I feel that the question title is not perfectly matching..

Comment: What *exactly* is unexpected? Why are you surprised? Do you know what type `(-1) * One` has?

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I edited my question to point at the real thing that I don't understand, which is why assigning a LONG to a LONGLONG is causing that left padding with zeros.

Comment: Perhaps you assume `LONG(-1) * One` has type `long`. That would be a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In expression `(-1) * (UINT)1`, the first operand gets converted to `UINT` according to [operand conversion rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> Otherwise, if the unsigned operand's conversion rank is greater or equal to the conversion rank of the signed operand, the signed operand is converted to the unsigned operand's type.

Therefore, we have an unsigned multiplication with result type of `UINT`. The conversion from `UINT` to `LONGLONG` is straightforward, since `LONGLONG` can represent every number representable by `UINT`, in this case `0xffffffff`. That's how you end up with `0x00000000ffffffff`.

Now, when you do `LONG(LONG(-1) * (UINT)1)`, the rule above still applies, though you end up converting unsigned `0xffffffff` to `-1`, which then gets sign-expanded to `LONGLONG`.

P.S: I am assuming Win32 / Win64 where UINT and LONG are 32-bit and LONGLONG is 64-bit.